# FPS counter for a simple Vulkan app

Tags: vulkan

What measurement/monitoring tools could I use to get the FPS values for a simple Vulkan app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a question related to programming of an FPS measurement or is it related to using tools to measure fps ?

Comment: @PaulHK I am looking for a tool to measure the FPS of my very simple app. I am new at this; nowhere near to instrumenting my application.

Comment: @Vectorizer: If it's your program, you should not be using FPS as a unit of performance measurement. Use the actual frame time instead; it's far more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try AMD's [OCAT](https://github.com/GPUOpen-Tools/OCAT) tool. It can overlay an FPS counter on a Vulkan or D3D12 app, similar to how FRAPS works for D3D11/OpenGL. (It should work on all Vulkan-supporting GPUs, btw, not just AMD ones.)

Answer (score 6):

You might want to try the VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor layer from the LunarG Vulkan SDK.

Download the SDK from the LunarXchange [site](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/).

After SDK installation, you can activate the layer by setting this environment variable:

```
VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor
```

The monitor layer displays the FPS value in the application window's title bar.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be helpful if you expanded on this and perhaps provided some links.

Comment: Cool stuff!.  @SimonF you just add the extension string to the array of your validation layers and it just works ))

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work for `vulkansdk-1.2.131.2` on ubuntu 19.10 for glfw-based app, although such layer loaded properly as inspected via `VK_LOADER_DEBUG=all`. But anyway, it works with vkcube.

Comment: Nowdays, with the `Vulkan Configurator` (included in the SDK) you can enable this layer more easily. Tested on Win10 x64.